# Setting the selected value of a Select element in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template that I am embedding in my html page. There is a select element with all of the available options already rendered. How can I set the selected value of the select list when I render my template?

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">      
    <div id="my-modal">
      <form action="/TestAction" method="post">
        <input id="MyId" name="MyId" type="hidden" value="{{MyId}}" />      
        <label for="Test">Test: (optional)</label>
        <select id="Test" name="Test">
          <option value="">-- Choose Test --</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to build out the option as part of the helper, you can use a combination of a small custom handlebars helper and parent context, denoted using the `../` syntax:

First write the helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('selected', function(option, value){
    if (option === value) {
        return ' selected';
    } else {
        return ''
    }
});
```

And then in your template you call your helper and pass in the parent context inside the `each` loop to check for `selectedState`

```
{{#each states}}
    <option value="{{this}}" {{selected this ../selectedState}}>{{this}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This solution is far better than accepted question.

Comment: Can I ask here similar question because I didn't find a answer in my own topic? This solution is something that I need but not quite...

Answer (score 9):

I took the `{{#each}}` helper as inspiration, and wrote a custom helper that does the same thing: loops over a list, and continually appends the contents of the arguments to an output string. (From here: [Handlebars block helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html))

In this case, I'm not passing in a chunk of template HTML to serve as the function's `options` parameter, like you would when using `{{#each}}`. Instead I am just building up the `<option>`
 tags by brute force, and testing every iteration of the `context` list. Lastly, I return a big long string of `<option></option>` tags, and hopefully one of them has `selected="selected"`.

The function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('options_selected', function(context, test) {
    var ret = '';
    for (var i = 0, len = context.length; i < len; i++) {
        var option = '<option value="' + context[i]+'"';
        if (test.toLowerCase() == context[i].toLowerCase()) {
            option += ' selected="selected"';
        }
        option += '>'+ Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(context[i]) + '</option>';
        ret += option;
    }

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(ret);
});
```

The tag in use:

```
<script id="form-state" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <select name="state">
    {{{options_selected states selectedState}}}
    </select>
</script>
```

Please suggest any edits that would improve this, thanks!

Comment: An improvement would be to print `context[i]` as `Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(context[i])`.

Comment: Might be trivial but I would rewrite your for loop as:
for(var i=0; len = context.length; i < len; i++)

http://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4

Answer (score 3):

You can use values straight in the Handlebars template like so.

**Handlebars Template**

```
<select id="distance">
        <option value="15" {{#if (isEqual 15 distance)}} selected {{/if}}>15</option>
        <option value="25" {{#if (isEqual 25 distance)}} selected {{/if}}>25</option>
        <option value="50" {{#if (isEqual 50 distance)}} selected {{/if}}>50</option>
        <option value="100" {{#if (isEqual 100 distance)}} selected {{/if}}>100</option>
        <option value="300" {{#if (isEqual 300 distance)}} selected {{/if}}>300</option>
</select>
```

**Handlebars Helper**

```
define(['hbs/handlebars'], function (Handlebars) {
  'use strict';

  Handlebars.registerHelper('isEqual', function (expectedValue, value) {
    return value === expectedValue;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (built over EmberJS to ease the JS part)

I refactored your sample a little, to have objects for proposed values, which can by the way carry the `selected` attribute...

The template part:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my-template">
    <div id="my-modal">
      <form action="/TestAction" method="post">
        <input id="MyId" name="MyId" type="hidden" value="{{MyId}}" />      
        <label for="Test">Test: (optional)</label>
        <select id="Test" name="Test">
          <option value="">-- Choose Test --</option>
          {{#each values}}
              <option {{bindAttr value="id" selected="selected"}}>{{label}}</option>
          {{/each}}
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
</script>
```

The JS part:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName: 'my-template'

    MyId: 42
    values: [{
        id: 1,
        label: '1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        label: '2'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        label: '3',
        selected: true
    }, {
        id: 4,
        label: '4'
    }]
```

You can try it @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/uRUc3/

Comment: Yeah, I understand how to render the entire select list in handlebars. The question is, if the select list options are already rendered on the server side, is there a way to select an option when we render the template.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem.

```
$('select').val(value);
```

This is how I solved it, I set the desired value with jQuery after rendering the template. Was surprisingly easy. (Maybe its also a way to keep the templates logicless)